# Static files not found when Docker container is running in Django React app

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am trying to run my Docker image to see it on my browser yet all that appears is an empty screen, upon inspection I see the following errors:

```sh
[2020-09-12 17:31:42 +0000] [12] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-12 17:31:42 +0000] [12] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (12)
[2020-09-12 17:31:42 +0000] [12] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-12 17:31:42 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
Not Found: /static/js/2.8ba00362.chunk.js
Not Found: /static/js/main.8eee128b.chunk.js
Not Found: /static/css/2.7253a256.chunk.css
Not Found: /static/css/main.a85cbe2c.chunk.css
```

The commands I have run are:
`docker build . -t projecthub` and `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name theprojecthub projecthub:latest`

I am very unsure why these static files are even being looked for, I cannot seem to find any reference to them in my code. Does anybody know what I should do?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM myfriendsaccount/django-npm:latest

RUN mkdir usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY frontend ./frontend
COPY backend ./backend

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/backend

ENV DJANGO_PRODUCTION=True
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python3 manage.py collectstatic && \
    python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
    python3 manage.py migrate && \
    gunicorn project_hub.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Here are the relevant parts of my `settings.py` file:

```py
DEBUG = True

if DEBUG:
    APP_URL = "http://localhost:8000/"
else:
    APP_URL = "https://" + PRODUCTION_URL + "/"

PRODUCTION_URL = 'mywebsite.com'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://localhost:3000', 'localhost', 'http://localhost:8000', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]', PRODUCTION_URL, '0.0.0.0']

...

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8000',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build/static'),
]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

This is what is inside my frontend/build/static:

[image: frontend/build/static files]

Comment: I would guess that your npm process was building those uniquely named artifacts, though it's only a guess.

Comment: More specifically those look like Webpack build output, and the `npm run build` sequence in the `frontend` directory should produce them.  You can try running `docker run --rm -it projecthub sh` to get an interactive debug shell running on that image, and seeing what files are actually getting produced; possibly clearing your browser cache will help as well.

Comment: Check if there are `/static` entry inside a `.dockerignore` file, check on container if folders are correctly copied